# How does type II vs type III ANOVA work when there are more than two categorical predictors?

Tags: anova, categorical-data, interaction, sums-of-squares

For a model with two categorical factors in the form:
X = A + B

Type I (used if the factors are balanced) calculates SS for each term in the model sequentially as follows:

SS(A) then
SS(B|A) = SS(A and B) - SS(A) then
SS(AB|A,B) = SS(A, B, AB) – SS(A,B)

Type II (Used if the factors are unbalanced and there is no significant interaction):

SS(A|B) then
SS(B|A) then
SS(AB|A,B) #Interaction is not taken into consideration when calculating SS for each main effect.

Type III (used if the factors are unbalanced and the interaction is significant):

SS(A|B, AB) then
SS(B|A, AB) then
SS(AB|A,B)

My questions are as follows:

1. How does this work when there are more than two categorical predictors e.g. A, B and C or a three-way interaction in the model?
2. When the data is unbalanced on what basis would you decide to use a type II over a type III e.g. would you only use a type III if the three-way interaction was significant (regardless of if the two way interactions were) or would you still use a type III ANOVA even if some or all of the two-way interactions were significant but not the three-way interaction?
3. How significant does an interaction need to be in order to justify a type III analysis over a type II with two or more factors. In the past I have had instances where, in a two factor model, the interaction was significant when running a type II ANOVA but not a type III (and vice versa). In these cases which type of ANOVA (type II or type III) would be preferable?

Comment: Came across a nice tutorial about ANOVA: [Everything You Always Wanted to Know About ANOVA But Were Afraid to Ask](https://blog.msbstats.info/posts/2021-05-25-everything-about-anova/). Since you've asked several questions about Type 3 ANOVA... And definitely don't be afraid to ask more questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With multiple categorical predictors or higher-level interactions,Type II and Type III ANOVAs follow the same principles as they do for simpler situations. With Type III, each factor or interaction is evaluated after considering *all other* factors and interactions. With Type II, each factor or interaction is evaluated after considering all factors and interactions that *don't* involve the factor or interaction being evaluated; that maintains the "principle of marginality."

Restricting Type II to situations without significant interactions is too limiting. The issue with interactions is that, if interactions aren't significant, then Type II can provide more power than Type III. There's no need to restrict Type II to models with "insignificant" or small interactions. Furthermore, choosing a later statistical test based on the results of a prior result or test on the same model, as you seem to suggest, would invalidate that later test. Inference from frequentist tests assumes that you chose the test without looking at model results first.

As Type II and Type III ANOVA test different hypotheses, the choice comes down to which hypothesis you wish to test. Do you want to test each factor or interaction term after *everything else* in the model has been accounted for? Then choose Type III. Do you want to test each factor or interaction term after accounting for all the *other* predictors and interactions, except for those at higher levels that involve the factor or interaction being tested? Then choose Type II. You might want to look at the links from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/394608/28500) for more detailed study.

With multiple levels of interactions, I find neither of those very easy to understand. In many circumstances you simply want to know whether a particular predictor, including all of its interactions, has any association with outcome. For that, [chunk tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27429/28500) are simple and useful. Sometimes, you are interested in comparing particular scenarios based on your model. Then you can restrict your comparisons to those scenarios. Think about whether you really need a global ANOVA at all, whether Type II or Type III.

Comment: Just for clarification in a model with a three way interaction (A*B*C) the SS for each of the two-way interactions e.g. A*B would be SS(AB| A, B, C, AC, BC) for type 2 and  SS (AB| A, B, C, AC, BC, ABC) for type 3. When it comes to a single factor e.g. A would the SS for this factor be SS (A|B, C) or SS (A| B, C, BC) for a type 2 ANOVA?

Comment: @Insect_biologist with Type II you would also have to first account for `BC` as it's a higher-level term that doesn't involve `A`. Thus `SS (A| B, C, BC)` is correct. The two-way interactions seem OK as you wrote them. If you use Type III, remember the caution to use sum contrasts or another orthogonal contrast for categorical predictors if you are using `car::Anova()` (and many other anova functions).